# How to Connect AWS DB with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, connection-timeout

I am trying to connect my AWS MYSQL DataBase, but I get this error.

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
```

I've searched and notice it could a matter of security, adding the IP to the Security Group rules, but it still didn't work.

```
<?php

$servername = "****-1.cdvmnfrkbalc.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com";
$port = 3306;
$username = "admin";
$password = "******";
//$dbname = "phpmyadmin";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername:3306", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully."; 
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

How can I connect my DB to AWS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To successfully connect to a MySQL RDS instance, you have to do 2 things:

1. set the inbound rules so you can connect from your development environment.
2. set the RDS instance to allow Public access.

Once you do these 2 tasks, you can connect. See this AWS tutorial on how we setup the RDS instance.

[Creating the Amazon Relational Database Service item tracker](https://github.com/scmacdon/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/Creating_rds_item_tracker)

Comment: It worked! I was not configuring my IP for TCP entry.